# Use of あたる in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 先輩たちが君に厳しく**あたる**のも
> 昔の自分と今の君を重ねてるからじゃないかな

Context: A rookie's senpais have been giving him a hard time and another character explains to him why.

The subtitles read as "The reason your senpais give such a hard time, might be because they see their past selves in you, don't you think?"

The dictionary says that 当たる is an intransitive verb that means "to be hit" but in this sentence the subject is clearly 先輩たち and the target of the verb is 君. Can someone kindly explain this to me?

Comment: あたる is a verb with a large number of meanings. See meaning 12: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 2):

This あたる means "to treat [someone] [harshly]".

From: デジタル大辞泉:

> #### [あたる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BD%93%E3%82%8B/#jn-4694)
>
> ㋓人に接する。人を待遇する。現在では、ひどく扱う場合に用いる。「つらく―・る」「家族に―・る」

Sometimes あたる means "to treat [someone] harshly" or "to vent one's anger on [someone/something]" on its own without saying 厳しく, つらく, 乱暴に, etc. For example, (切れて)物に当たる means "to lose temper and handle things roughly in anger".